# vb.net Cannot update. Getting error "Database or object is read-only." when just trying to READ from excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledbconnection

I'm more than willing to accept other suggestions on ways to accomplish what I want to do. I am trying to read some lines from an excel spreadsheet that the user uploads to my application. The web server where this will eventually reside does not have excel installed on it, which makes referencing things like Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll in my project impossible. So I've been looking for ways to read the excel file so that will work with this situation. The best way I've found so far is to use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to connect to the excel file like a datasource. Here is a small snippet of I've put together so far:

```
Dim excelFileName As String = "C:\\Import\\K12Mercury.xlsx"
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & excelFileName & "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'"))
conn.Open()
```

The program fails on the `conn.Open()` line with the error:

> cannot update. database or object is read-only

I don't know why this is happening or if this is even the best route to use to be able to read from an excel file in an environment where excel is not installed. Will someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need the ACE oledb provider for xlsx. Not 100% sure though. Try `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;...`

Comment: Seeing the \\ twice in a path is new to me. Definitely try the Ace provider. You may have to try the 32 bit and the 64 bit before success.

Comment: [https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsx-files/](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsx-files/)

Comment: XLSX files require the ACE.OLEDB.12 drivers ([Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) pay attention to 32/64 bit versions) and be sure that you have read/write permissions for the user that tries to open that file (Using OleDB requires also to be able to write to the file)